# Statistical test to use to compare EMG waveforms with only the mean and sd?

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, curves

I have to compare processed EMG waveforms (smooth curves) that I recorded from 7 different leg muscles of 4 different subjects to reference EMG data (Winter book).
The problem is that for the reference EMG data I have only the mean and the sd for each time point (51 time point).
Therefore I want to test if there is a significant difference between the EMG waveforms I recorded and the reference EMG waveforms based only on the mean and sd but I don't know which is the best statistical test to use...

Somebody can help me please??

I also want if it's possible to analyze all the muscle together and not one muscle at a time.

PS : here is graphs of the mean + sd for the experimental and reference data of only one subject

Best,

Menor

[image: EMG waveforms of 7 leg muscles (2 conditions / mean and sd)[1]]